Firewall limit not working when using vpn
I have a ufw firewall with the following rules:
Status: active Logging: on (low) Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed) New profiles: skip
To Action From
22/tcp LIMIT IN Anywhere
80 LIMIT IN Anywhere
443 LIMIT IN Anywhere
22/tcp (v6) LIMIT IN Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6) LIMIT IN Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6) LIMIT IN Anywhere (v6)
These rules set a limit to the number of requests on ports 22, 80 and 443. The rules are obeyed except when I use a vpn like ExpressVPN. Port 22 still has a limit but ports 80 and 443 are no longer limited from a vpn.
How can I set a limit to the number of requests in order to block a hacker that hides behind a vpn?
